# How to force Firefox to load Google in non-HTTPS

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-12.04, redirection, https

When I type `http://www.google.co.uk` in the URL bar Firefox rewrites it as `https://www.google.co.uk`. This is a problem for me as HTTPS is blocked on my network for content filtering purposes.

Until a few days ago this was not the case, but during some experimentation I seem to have visited the HTTPS version of the site once or twice and also had the **HTTPS Everywhere** addon installed for a time. Now, no matter what I do Firefox redirects there. Sometimes it doesn't; sometimes I load the browser and the HTTP version loads fine, but then the next time it's oddly trying HTTPS again and nothing can shift it until a few session restarts later. I don't understand why it seems to sporadically use HTTP and HTTPS.

I'm using Firefox 23.0 and Ubuntu 12.04.

I've tried a number of things so far:

1. Setting `browser.urlbar.autoFill false`, `browser.urlbar.autoFill.typed false`, `browser.formfill.saveHttpsForms false`
2. Clearing *everything* from history
3. Resetting Firefox and using safe mode
4. Deleting all the profile data in `.mozilla` folder and creating a
   new profile
5. Completely purging Firefox and deleting `.mozilla`, `/etc/firefox`
   and reinstalling

How can I fix this so that Firefox just loads Google in non-HTTPS?

Maybe it's Google doing the redirect, but I just don't understand why it was fine until a few days ago, and also why it only does it sporadically.

Even when I try typing in `nosslsearch.google.com` I get redirected to the HTTPS version!

Lastly, when I log into another user account on the computer, and try Firefox with Google I see no problems with redirects, just as it had always been until recently on the above account.

**EDIT**: I should also mention I am not logged into any Google account.

Comment: What if you try `http://216.239.32.20` ? This is the IP for nosslsearch.google.com. I tried it (always logged in with Google) and got to a non-signed in http Google page.

Comment: @Rik that does seem to work. Interesting. Why?

Comment: You can always add `216.239.32.20 google.com www.google.com` in your hosts file so you always get to the http and you never use the https variant. It's not perfect but works. I don't know why it's happening in your user-account and not another.

Comment: @ Rik thanks, that will be a good temporary fix at the very least. It could be that Google or Firefox have changed something in the last few days, but for me it seems strange that I also visited the `https` site and played with `https_everywhere` extension in the last week too (plus the other account being fine still). Nevertheless, even clean installs of Firefox still bring no joy, so I am lost with what else to try. Alas.

Comment: > "HTTPS is blocked on my network for content filtering purposes." — my advice is **change your job,** seriously. (and if this your home ISP, then it's just pure madness).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed using Fiddler that sending HTTP requests to Google would always return the 302s you mention, redirecting me to the HTTPS url **as long as a Firefox user agent string was included in the request header**. This is my current user agent string using Firefox 24 on Windows 7 x64:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0`

So for me, a simple fix was to start using the [User Agent Quick Switch](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/user-agent-quick-switch/) add-on for Firefox. I changed my user agent string like this - just removed the `Firefox/24.0` at the end:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101`

I'd guess a similar change to your Ubuntu user agent string would also do the trick, although there is an outside chance that it be problematic on another site.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in to Google with a Google user account, Google will serve everything in https, so be sure you are logged out of all Google accounts.

Comment: Yes, I am not logged in or anything. I should have mentioned that --- question has been edited now.

Comment: @fpghost Did you try removing the Firefox package through the Software Center, rebooting, then reinstalling?

Comment: No, not tried via Software Center, just the purge and deletions followed by reinstall. I will give it a go if you think it might make a difference...

Comment: I can't say for sure it will fix it, but it's something I would try, especially since so many other changes have been made it may be difficult to get Firefox back to working normally if the problem were otherwise identified.

Comment: I've now done the remove from the Software Center, along with removing everything I could see relating to firefox in Synaptic Package Manager (marking for Complete Removal). Then I deleted `.mozilla`,`.adobe`, `.macromedia` from ~ and `/etc/firefox/`, `/usr/lib/firefox` and `/usr/lib/firefox-addons`. I then rebooted and reinstalled firefox from the Software Center. Unfortunately the problem still persists. Yet on the other user account things are fine...

Comment: @fpghost If this is something unique to the user, then I would guess there is some setting somewhere in the user's `home` directory that is causing this behavior. I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with Ubuntu Desktop to tell you where to look. I had an issue related to a user on a server that I couldn't track down and ended up just deleting the user and making a new one with the same name, being sure to delete the user's home directory (backing up anything important, of course).

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is determined from the server. If you look the over the request you will find that we are requesting for http://wwww.google.co.in but the response returns https://www.google.co.in with the status code 302. So that means server redirects the `http` request to `https`

Here is what I observed in developer console of firefox.

[image]

Comment: I had seen that in the console also. Still I can't understand why this was not happening until a few days ago (it seems too coincidental with me visiting the https site and mucking around with https everywhere, unless it just so happens google made a major change then also). Secondly, I don't see the behaviour on the firefox on my other user account when I visit http google (no redirects there), which makes me think something local must be happening too.

Comment: Also if it is the server, why does even `nosslsearch.google.com` redirect back to https? seems a very odd behaviour.